# Django 1.7 datamigration and user groups

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm trying to implement a datamigration using django 1.7 native migration system. Here is what I've done.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


def create_basic_user_group(apps, schema_editor):
    """Forward data migration that create the basic_user group

    """
    Group = apps.get_model('auth', 'Group')
    Permission = apps.get_model('auth', 'Permission')
    group = Group(name='basic_user')
    group.save()

    perm_codenames = (
        'add_stuff',
        '...',
    )

    # we prefere looping over all these in order to be sure to fetch them all
    perms = [Permission.objects.get(codename=codename)
             for codename in perm_codenames]

    group.permissions.add(*perms)
    group.save()


def remove_basic_user_group(apps, schema_editor):
    """Backward data migration that remove the basic_user group

    """
    group = Group.objects.get(name='basic_user')
    group.delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    """This migrations automatically create the basic_user group.

    """

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_basic_user_group, remove_basic_user_group),
    ]
```

But when I try to run the migration, I got a LookupError exception telling me that no app with label 'auth' could be found.

How can I create my groups in a clean way that could also be used in unit tests ?

Comment: Try `app.get_registered_model` and/or depend on `('auth', 'group')`.

This is kind of a random advice, since I am still in the process of understanding the registry stuff myself. It helped me fix a similar issue though.

Comment: In django 1.8 the object mananagers can be available during the migrations. In particular now your code should work as-is

Answer (score 6):

I've done what you are trying to do. The problems are:

1. The documentation for [1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#accessing-models-from-other-apps) and [1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#accessing-models-from-other-apps) is quite clear: If you want to access a model from another app, you must list this app as a dependency:

   > When writing a `RunPython` function that uses models from apps other than the one in which the migration is located, the migration’s dependencies attribute should include the latest migration of each app that is involved, otherwise you may get an error similar to: `LookupError: No installed app with label 'myappname'` when you try to retrieve the model in the `RunPython` function using `apps.get_model()`.

   So you should have a dependency on the latest migration in `auth`.
2. As you mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135523/django-1-7-datamigration-and-user-groups#comment43282037_27413223) you will run into an issue whereby the permissions you want to use are not created yet. The problem is that the permissions are created by signal handler attached to the `post_migrate` signal. So the permissions associated with any *new* model created in a migration are not available until the migration is *finished*.

   You can fix this by doing this at the start of `create_basic_user_group`:

   ```
   from django.contrib.contenttypes.management import update_contenttypes
   from django.apps import apps as configured_apps
   from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions

   for app in configured_apps.get_app_configs():
       update_contenttypes(app, interactive=True, verbosity=0)

   for app in configured_apps.get_app_configs():
       create_permissions(app, verbosity=0)
   ```

   This will also create the content types for each model (which are also created *after* the migration), see below as to why you should care about that.

   Perhaps you could be more selective than I am in the code above: update just some key apps rather than update all apps. I've not tried to be selective. Also, it is possible that both loop could be merged into one. I've not tried it with a single loop.
3. You get your `Permission` objects by searching by `codename` but `codename` is not guaranteed to be unique. Two apps can have models called `Stuff` and so you could have an `add_stuff` permission associated with two different apps. If this happens, your code will fail. What you should do is search by `codename` and `content_type`, which are guaranteed to be unique together. A unique `content_type` is associated with each model in the project: two models with the same name but in different apps will get two different content types.

   This means adding a dependency on the `contenttypes` app, and using the `ContentType` model: `ContentType = apps.get_model("contenttypes", "ContentType")`.

Answer (score 2):

As said in https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23422, the signal `post_migrate` should be sent before dealing with Permission objects.

But there is a helper function already on Django to sent the needed signal: `django.core.management.sql.emit_post_migrate_signal`

Here, it worked this way:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
from django.core.management.sql import emit_post_migrate_signal


PERMISSIONS_TO_ADD = [
    'view_my_stuff',
    ...
]


def create_group(apps, schema_editor):
    # Workarounds a Django bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23422
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    try:
        emit_post_migrate_signal(2, False, 'default', db_alias)
    except TypeError:  # Django < 1.8
        emit_post_migrate_signal([], 2, False, 'default', db_alias)

    Group = apps.get_model('auth', 'Group')
    Permission = apps.get_model('auth', 'Permission')

    group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='MyGroup')
    permissions = [Permission.objects.get(codename=i) for i in PERMISSIONS_TO_ADD]
    group.permissions.add(*permissions)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0001_initial'),
        ('myapp', '0002_mymigration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_group),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I figure out how to solve this problem and I get the following exit: get_model will only fetch Your model apps. I don't have sure about if this would be a good pratice, but it worked for me.

I just invoked the model Directly and made the changes.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models, migrations
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


def create_groups(apps, schema_editor):
    g = Group(name='My New Group')
    g.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_groups)
    ]
```

And then, just apply a /manage.py migrate to finish.
I hope it helps.

Comment: This works, but you can't add permissions to them since they are created on a post-migration signals. In fact, you will think it works if you migrate an already existing db since permission objects have been created on a previous migration. But it will fail on a migration targeting a new and empty db.