# Django admin - model visible to superuser, not staff user

Tags: mysql, django, django-admin, migration

I am aware of `syncdb` and `makemigrations`, but we are restricted to do that in production environment.

We recently had couple of tables created on production. As expected, tables were not visible on admin for any user.
Post that, we had below 2 queries executed manually on production sql (*i ran migration on my local and did `show create table` query to fetch raw sql*)

**django_content_type**

```
INSERT INTO django_content_type(name, app_label, model) 
values ('linked_urls',"urls", 'linked_urls');
```

**auth_permission**

```
INSERT INTO auth_permission (name, content_type_id, codename) 
values 
('Can add linked_urls Table', (SELECT id FROM django_content_type where model='linked_urls' limit 1) ,'add_linked_urls'),
('Can change linked_urls Table', (SELECT id FROM django_content_type where model='linked_urls' limit 1) ,'change_linked_urls'),
('Can delete linked_urls Table', (SELECT id FROM django_content_type where model='linked_urls' limit 1) ,'delete_linked_urls');
```

Now this model is visible under super-user and is able to grant access to staff users as well, but staff users cant see it.
Is there any table entry that needs to be entered in it?

Or is there any other way to do a solve this problem without *syncdb*, *migrations*?

Comment: There might be a group for _staff_ users. Did you grant permissions to it?

Comment: yes, also, there are lot of standalone staff users not belonging to any group!

Comment: Then I'd suggest to create the user-Group `staff` and assign it to all staff users. I'm not into that, but it should be possible to handle the assignment by one SQL command, too.

Comment: just tried, created a group, gave access of models to that group...assigned it to user.No Luck still.cant see the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally i had a solution.I did lot of debugging on django and apparanetly below function (*at `django.contrib.auth.backends`*) does the job for providing permissions.

```
def _get_permissions(self, user_obj, obj, from_name):
    """
    Returns the permissions of `user_obj` from `from_name`. `from_name` can
    be either "group" or "user" to return permissions from
    `_get_group_permissions` or `_get_user_permissions` respectively.
    """
    if not user_obj.is_active or user_obj.is_anonymous() or obj is not None:
        return set()

    perm_cache_name = '_%s_perm_cache' % from_name
    if not hasattr(user_obj, perm_cache_name):
        if user_obj.is_superuser:
            perms = Permission.objects.all()
        else:
            perms = getattr(self, '_get_%s_permissions' % from_name)(user_obj)
        perms = perms.values_list('content_type__app_label', 'codename').order_by()
        setattr(user_obj, perm_cache_name, set("%s.%s" % (ct, name) for ct, name in perms))
    return getattr(user_obj, perm_cache_name)
```

**So what was the issue?**

Issue lied in this query :

```
INSERT INTO django_content_type(name, app_label, model) 
values ('linked_urls',"urls", 'linked_urls');
```

looks fine initially but actual query executed was :

```
--# notice the caps case here - it looked so trivial, i didn't even bothered to look into it untill i realised what was happening internally
INSERT INTO django_content_type(name, app_label, model) 
values ('Linked_Urls',"urls", 'Linked_Urls');
```

So django, internally, when doing `migrate`, ensures everything is migrated in **lower case** - *and this was the problem*!!

I had a separate query executed to lower case all the previous inserts and *voila*!

Answer (score 4):

> We recently had couple of tables created on production.

I can read what you wrote there in two ways.

First way: you created tables with SQL statements, for which there are no corresponding models in Django. If this is the case, no amount of fiddling with content types and permissions that will make Django suddenly use the tables. You need to create models for the tables. Maybe they'll be [unmanaged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.managed), but they need to exist.

Second way: the corresponding models in Django do exist, you just manually created tables for them, so that's not a problem. What I'd do in this case is run the following code, explanations follow after the code:

```python
from django.contrib.contenttypes.management import update_contenttypes
from django.apps import apps as configured_apps
from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions

for app in configured_apps.get_app_configs():
    update_contenttypes(app, interactive=True, verbosity=0)

for app in configured_apps.get_app_configs():
    create_permissions(app, verbosity=0)
```

What the code above does is essentially perform the work that Django performs *after* it runs migrations. When the migration occurs, Django just creates tables as needed, then when it is done, it calls `update_contenttypes`, which scans the table associated with the models defined in the project and adds to the `django_content_type` table whatever needs to be added. Then it calls `create_permissions` to update `auth_permissions` with the add/change/delete permissions that need adding. I've used the code above to force permissions to be created early [during a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30362414/1906307). It is useful if I have a data migration, for instance, that creates groups that need to refer to the new permissions.

Comment: its the second way you have mentioned.Now, my problem is i do not have access to run things on shell on prod / pre-prod.Is there any raw `sql` stuff which i can pass on to DBA's to have query executed and get the job done?

Comment: You don't have that problem. Any Django management command can be run by calling `django.core.management.call_command` from python code. If you create a view that wraps that function, you can run anything you want. But, when in doubt, you can also call a command from python and as such a Django view using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) library. And yes, both ways would allow you to run migrations.